# How to count number of arguments to a format string in C?

Tags: c

I've got a program that takes a format string from the command line which represents the format for the filenames of multiple output files.  It should take just a single integer argument that can be substituted in to generate the real output filenames, and I'd like to verify that when doing my input checking. What's a good way to determine the number of arguments a format string expects in C?

Comment: If you don't need the full generality of `printf`, why not use a simpler structure for your templates, so that you can verify it easily?

Comment: What format string? `printf`'s? Can you post some sort of example at least?

Comment: Sorry, yes, printf style format string.  And I don't really want to have to hassle with parsing a custom format when printf is readily available to do everything I'd conceivable need.

Comment: @gct As you obviously can **not** do everything you'd need, ...

Comment: https://gist.github.com/alfwatt/279b694f702d0d6910cd259ce427dfc3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of arguments accepted depends on the version of your C library (for example, `%a` conversion specifiers were added in C99).  You can be certain that it is no greater than the number of unescaped `%` characters (i.e., the number of `%` characters remaining after all `%%` sequences are removed) plus the number of `*` characters (which could be width specifiers).

You should consider security issues, though; if the user supplies a `%n` format specifier this could result in a write to an arbitrary memory location.  In other cases, supplying e.g. `%f` would result in garbage values being output, `%s` in arbitrary memory contents, and even with `%d` specifiers allowing the user to supply a field width e.g. `%255d` could result in buffer overflow.  It would be smarter to consider a different formatting scheme e.g. replacing a token (which could still be `%d`), but not allowing the user to supply a `printf` format string.

Comment: C99 would be a fine choice I think.  "no greater than" may be sufficient for what I need.

Comment: I'm operating in a trusted environment, so I'm not very worried about security issues, still good to know though.  I think you're right I'll just replace a token in the given string with my file number.

Comment: "*...  It would be smarter to consider a different formatting scheme e.g. replacing a token (which could still be %d), but not allowing the user to supply a printf format string. ...*" Yes, yes, yes - **much** smarter!

Comment: "I'm operating in a trusted environment" No bugs can be trusted :D

Comment: What about the format string `"%*.*s"`, which has exactly one `%` but requires three arguments, two `int`s and a `char*`.

Answer (score 1):

The GNU C library contains a function `parse_printf_format` that can be used in your case. From [the glibc manual, section 12.12.10 - *Parsing a template string*](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Parsing-a-Template-String.html):

> You can use the function parse_printf_format to obtain information about the number and types of arguments that are expected by a given template string. This function permits interpreters that provide interfaces to printf to avoid passing along invalid arguments from the user’s program, which could cause a crash.

> parse_printf_format returns the total number of arguments required by template. If this number is greater than n, then the information returned describes only the first n arguments. If you want information about additional arguments, allocate a bigger array and call parse_printf_format again.

Usecase example:

```c
#include <printf.h>
size_t arguments_count = parse_printf_format ("Your discount: %d%%\n", 0, NULL);
/* arguments_count now holds a value of 1 */
```